# AttributeError: module 'keras' has no attribute 'utils'

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, anaconda

I was trying to use Keras to classify movie reviews into their respective sentiment classes (positive or negative).

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
import numpy as np

# Preprocessing the Data
X = np.array(X) / 255.0
y = keras.utils.to_categorical(y)
```

But it gives me following error when i run the code:

```
 ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [41], in <cell line: 2>()
      1 # Importing Required Libraries
----> 2 import tensorflow as tf
      3 from tensorflow import keras
      4 import numpy as np


File ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\applications\inception_resnet_v2.py:324, in <module>
    320         x = layers.Activation(activation, name=ac_name)(x)
    321     return x
--> 324 @keras.utils.register_keras_serializable()
    325 class CustomScaleLayer(keras_layers.Layer):
    326     def __init__(self, scale, **kwargs):
    327         super().__init__(**kwargs)

AttributeError: module 'keras' has no attribute 'utils'
```

versions that i use:

```
Python - 3.9.12
keras - 2.12.0
tensorflow - 2.12.0
```

Answer (score 0):

There will be an issue with How you installed `TensorFlow` or Anaconda Navigator in your system because the error is when you try to import the `TensorFlow`.

1. Please re-verify if you have followed all the steps mentioned in this [link](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/pip#macos_1) to install TensorFlow as per your system OS.
2. or You can try again by creating and activating new VirEnv in conda.

Let us know if the issue still persists.

(Attaching the replicated code screenshot below for your reference:)[image]

Answer (score 0):

Install keras and tensorflow, after restart your kernel.

```
pip install keras tensorflow
```